# Как установить X-Frame-Options DENY на WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как установить X-Frame-Options DENY на WordPress? Возможно ли включение его снова при работающих плагинах кеширование?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В начало файла `functions.php` активной темы (после `<?php`) вставьте строку

```
header('X-Frame-Options: deny');
```

Установка заголовков в php работает только в том случае, если до этого не производился вывод на экран. Если в вашем случае работать не будет, отключите все плагины поочерёдно, смените тему на стандартную, чтобы понять, где проблема. Правильно написанные плагины и темы не должны ничего выводить на экран до того момента, как начнётся выполнения файла `functions.php` темы.

После активации плагинов кеширования заголовок должен сохраниться. по крайней мере, плагин WP Super Cache не препятсвует выводу этого заголовка. Можете проверить на моём тестовом сайте http://test.kagg.eu/. Плагин кеширования включён, что видно по исходному коду страницы - в самом низу есть комментарий

```
<!-- Cached page generated by WP-Super-Cache on 2018-10-13 11:05:18 -->
```

А во вкладке Networks dev tools можно увидеть сам заголовок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Оказывается все  проще простого